# How to find out if a "-replace" actually did anything

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm fairly familiar with PowerShell, and I'm using `Get-Content` piped into a string replacement expression. However, I'd like to only write the "new" content back to the file if something actually changed.

I've been using a simple new/old file content comparison, but on larger files it's pretty slow (like, terribly slow). It occurred to me that the regex replacement is actually running quite quickly, so if there some way to ask PowerShell after a replacement was done, whether anything was found, that would be ideal. If no changes were made, simply don't write the file back out.

I tried testing `$Matches.count` but I get

> The variable '$Matches' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.

Am I missing something? I didn't really want to look for matches before doing the replacement, because that also seems wasteful (and violates tell-don't-ask).

Here's how I'm doing it currently:

```
function Convert-ToUTF8 {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]] $File)
    process {
        $File |
            %{
                $fileFullName = $_

                Write-Verbose "Loading $filefullname..."
                $content = (Get-Content $fileFullName)

                Write-Verbose "   Fixing xml prolog..."
                $newcontent = $content -replace '^<\?xml version="(\d+\.\d+)" encoding="(.+)"\?>$', '<?xml version="$1" encoding="UTF-8"?>'

                Write-Verbose "   Checking to see if there were changes..."
                $changed = $newcontent -ne $content

                if ($changed) {
                    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("Write changes to $filefullname")) {
                        Write-Host "Writing changes to $filefullname..."
                        $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
                        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($fileFullName, $newcontent, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
                    }
                } else {
                    Write-Host "No changes to $filefullname."
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify? I suspect you may just use  a temp variable, assign old value to it, run replace, and compare the result to the old value.

Comment: Yep that's basically it.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell `-replace` won't populate `$Matches`, comparing before-and-after is indeed the way to go. That being said, I'd suggest not editing XML files using regex -powershell has plenty support for interacting with and modifying XML without the need for regex

Comment: Yeah I thought about editing as XML, though since it's in source control I was trying to avoid any other formatting changes. Yes, most comparison tools can be set to ignore those, but I really prefer the source history to highlight what exactly was changed.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>It's been pointed out that proper XML parsing is generally preferable, but you've clarified that you need to keep the exact formatting of the input file for the purposes of distraction-free diffing later.</sup>

---

Indeed, **the only way to tell if a `-replace` operation actually performed a replacement is to compare the input string to the result string.**

(As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, only the `-match` operator (and `switch -regex`)  populate the automatic `$Matches` variable reflecting the results of the regex-matching operation).

In the simplest case:

```bash
$original = 'foo'
$potentiallyModified = $original -replace 'x', 'y'

$replacementWasMade = $original -cne $potentiallyModified
```

Note:

- `-cne`rather than `-ne` is used to perform case-*sensitive* comparison, to also detect the case where the replacement only changed the casing of the input string.
- Conceivably, an *effective no-op* replacement may have been performed (e.g., `'foo' -replace 'o', 'o'`), which the above doesn't detect; that said, while a new `[string]` instance is returned in such cases, that usually doesn't matter, given that strings are usually compared by *value* equality, not *reference* equality - see below.

*If* performance is paramount in this scenario - I doubt that it matters in most cases - you can apply the following **micro-optimization**, taking advantage of the ([documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace)) fact that if the specified regex does *not* match, the input string is returned *as-is* (the very same `[string]` instance):

```bash
$original = 'foo'
$potentiallyModified = $original -replace 'x', 'y'

# Test for reference equality.
$replacementWasMade = 
  -not [object]::ReferenceEquals($original, $potentiallyModified)
```

---

**Your specific use case:**

**You must use `$content = (Get-Content -Raw $fileFullName)`, i.e., the `-Raw` switch** to read the input file *as a single string* and to perform your `-replace` operation on that *single string*.

Otherwise you'll get an *array*  of lines, and the behavior of `-eq` *changes* with an array-valued LHS to perform *filtering* of the LHS rather than returning a Boolean.

Additionally, your `-eq` RHS will be an array too (the array of lines with potentially modified line(s)), which is coerced to a *single string* with elements separated by a space, which means that it won't work as intended:

```bash
PS> 'foo', 'bar' -eq 'foo', 'bar'
 # !! NO OUTPUT
```

That is, the RHS was coerced to single string 'foo bar', which matched neither LHS element, so an *empty array* was returned.

As for **performance**:

To speed up file I/O, avoid cmdlets altogether and use .NET types directly:

```bash
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileFullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the compare:

```
$xmlContent = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlContent = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filePath))

$header     = $xmlContent.xml
$headerNew  = $xmlContent.xml -replace 'version="(\d+\.\d+)" encoding="(.+)"', 'version="$1" encoding="UTF-8"' 

if( $header -ne $headerNew ) {
    $xmlContent.xml    = $headerNew
    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
    [void][System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($filePath, $xmlContent.OuterXml, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}
```